# How to use different font families for the same unicode block in ucharclases?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode, ucharclasses, fontfamily

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[Sinhala,Latin]{ucharclasses}

\newfontfamily\FooBarr{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\sinhala{Noto Sans Sinhala}
\newfontfamily\sinhalaa{Noto Serif Sinhala}
\setDefaultTransitions{\FooBarr}{}
\setTransitionTo{Sinhala}{\sinhalaa}

\begin{document}
ananother word {\sinhala මගේ වායුපායානයේ} {\sinhalaa ආඳන් පිරී ඇත.}
\end{document}
```

Is there a graceful way to change from one font family to another for the same unicode block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can offer you a “family-aware” switching command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[Sinhala,Latin]{ucharclasses}

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[NFSSFamily=standardserif]
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}[NFSSFamily=standardsans]

\newfontfamily\sinhalaserif{Noto Serif Sinhala}[
  NFSSFamily=sinhalaserif,
]
\newfontfamily\sinhalasans{Noto Sans Sinhala}[
  NFSSFamily=sinhalasans,
]

\setDefaultTransitions{\switchto{standard}}{}
\setTransitionTo{Sinhala}{\switchto{sinhala}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\switchto}{m}
 {
  \str_case_e:vnF {f@family}
   {
    { standardsans } { \fontfamily{#1sans}\selectfont }
    { sinhalasans } { \fontfamily{#1sans}\selectfont }
   }
   { \fontfamily{#1serif}\selectfont }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case_e:nnF { v }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

a word මගේ වායුපායානයේ

\textsf{a word  ආඳන් පිරී ඇත.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach, which exploits what [`xeCJK`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xecjk) can do with other languages beyond CJK:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{xeCJK}% loads fontspec
\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{HangulJamo}{"200D,"0D80 -> "0DFF}
% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhala_(Unicode_block)+ZWJ
% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner
% The HangulJamo class has the property that no additional code is inserted
% between characters within this class.
\xeCJKsetup{CJKspace=true}
% Keep spaces between characters.
\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{HalfLeft}{"2018, "201C}
\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{HalfRight}{%
  "00B7, "2019, "201D, "2013, "2014, "2025, "2026, "2027, "2E3A}
% In Unicode, some Latin and CJK punctuation marks share the same code points.
% We make sure that these punctuation marks are the Latin ones.

\setmainfont{NotoSerif-Regular.ttf}
\setsansfont{NotoSans-Regular.ttf}
\setCJKmainfont{NotoSerifSinhala-Regular.ttf}
\setCJKsansfont{NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf}

\newcommand\test{%
  My hovercraft is full of eels.\par % ;-)
  මාගේ වායු පා යානයේ ආඳන් පිරී ඇත.\par
}
\begin{document}
\test
\medskip
{\sffamily
\test}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Drawbacks? Well, the documentation of `xeCJK` is only available in Chinese…

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly with `ucharclasses`, but `babel` supports the Sinhala language with font families.  It requires some tagging, but you appear to be using a `\sinhala` command anyway.  Keep using XeLaTeX (it might also work in HarfTeX.)

```
\documentclass{article}
% To fit within a TeX.SX MWE:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[import]{Sinhala}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{Noto Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[Sinhala]{rm}{Noto Serif Sinhala}
\babelfont[Sinhala]{sf}{Noto Sans Sinhala}

\begin{document}

A word.

\foreignlanguage{Sinhala}{මගේ වායුපායානයේ}

\sffamily

Another word.

\foreignlanguage{Sinhala}{ආඳන් පිරී ඇත.}

\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Sinhala sample]

You’ll get some harmless warnings about fonts not containing the language “English.”  You can suppress them if you want by replacing the `[english]` package option with `\babelprovide[import, main, language=Default]{english}`, but note that the package maintainer doesn’t recommend that.